# Change theme manually from files without starting eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

After installing the color IDE pack on Eclipse Luna, my Eclipse no longer will start.  How can I point eclipse to the default theme without starting the application?

It launched the first time after installing the pack, but when I changed to one of the pack themes, it crashed and no longer will start up.  It seems it is unable to start with the selected theme I chose.  i want to revert to default.

Answer (score 0):

The theme setting is in the workspace in the

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings
```

folder in the

```
org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.prefs
```

file, and looks like:

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
themeid=org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_classic
```

for the Classic theme