# Eclipse not opening, NoSuchFieldError: useDarkestDarkColors

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse not opening anymore. In .metadata/log file,it says:

> !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: useDarkestDarkColors

And eclipse open like this,can't click anywhere, I think the problem is eclipse's darkest dark theme. Is there a way to set back to the default theme without using 
Eclipse menu -> Window -> Preference -> General -> Editors -> "Restore Defaults" 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the **org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme.prefs** file by following the instructions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31277615/9247260). You can try setting

```
enableddarkestdark=false
```

or

```
themeid=org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.theme.e4_default
```

Comment: Ok, have you tried to reinstall eclipse or is that no option?